# Razor Layout is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Why is this page doesn't display the layout or ViewBag.Title? "MyChart" renders ok but when the "Write" function invoked, it replaces all page content with rendered image. Is there a way to add more content to the page after or before I render an image ?

```
@model cmCase.Models.xyz

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="well">
    @{
        var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
            .AddTitle("Most Popular")
            .AddSeries(name: "Employee", xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },  yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
            .AddSeries(name: "Employee12", xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })                    
            .Write();
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like that requires a two step process.

"*The first step is to create a page that generates the chart*"

"*The second step is to display the resulting image in another page.*"

as described here [using charts in razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart)